# SQL Syntax Error - Can anyone help me fix it

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

It is really simple but I am unexperienced in SQL, and also I have no idea why this syntax error occurs. Any help is appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO "zr_mem"('email', 'pwd', 'code') VALUES ('test@test.com','213123','324')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: table name should be `zr_mem`  backtick  not double quotes

Answer (score 3):

You have to use backticks instead of single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO zr_mem(`email`, `pwd`, `code`) VALUES 
('test@test.com','213123','324')
```

Comment: keep mind that you normally does not have to use backticks or dq.. to specify column names unless it has spaces or you actually using  reserved characters

Answer (score 3):

you have to use backticks (below key of Esc key) instead of ''

```
INSERT INTO zr_mem(`email`, `pwd`, `code`) VALUES ('test@test.com','213123','324')
```

100% working ☺

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way:

```
insert into `zr_mem`(email,pwd,code) values('test@test.com','$213123','324')
```